# Restrict Access to Site Usage Analytics Page for Users with Visitors Permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, analytics

I am trying to restrict access to Site Usage Analytics for `Visitors`. The site analytics should not be shared with visitors, only with Administrators or Members, I do not see any logic with this default of displaying site analytics to visitors.

In short, I want the `Visitors` to be able to do the same things as per default, but only restrict access to `siteanalytics.aspx`.

The solutions provided online include mostly removing the `View Application Pages` permission, but that has side effects (mostly with the navigation elements and other form elements).

[image: Site Usage]